# How to capture partial amount

Tags: magento, payment

I have two types of product in my store first one is downloadable and second one is physical so we want to capture the amount only for downloadable product and remaining will captured from admin whenever parcel is ready for shipment.

So my question is how to achieve this functionality so that remaining amount should be available for capture later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set your credit card setting in admin to  'authorize only'

Then create a custom module with observer that do a partial invoice automatically for downloadable products only (captured) after each order is place. The remaining amount will be capture as admin invoice/ship items.

See [Partial Invoicing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/267433/#t362454)